# Trying to run headless chrome in nodejs using mocha but it gives me an error

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, mocha.js

Below is the code to run test headless in nodejs using mocha. But I keep getting "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input" can someone help ?

```
var assert = require('assert');
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
              By = webdriver.By,
              until = webdriver.until;
var test = require('selenium-webdriver/testing');  
var driver;
const timeOut = 15000;      

const chromeCapabilities = webdriver.Capabilities.chrome();
chromeCapabilities.set('chromeOptions', {args: ['--headless', '--disable-gpu','--no-sandbox','--disable-dev-shm-usage']});





var site_root_url = "file://" + __dirname + "/../../site"

String.prototype.contains = function(it) { return this.indexOf(it) != -1; };

test.describe('Browser Headless', function() {

  test.before(function() {
  });
  
  test.after(function() {
  });

  test.beforeEach(function() {
    // this.timeout(timeOut);
  });

  // test cases

  var url = "";

    

  test.it("Headless with Chrome", function() {
    this.timeout(timeOut);    
    
    driver = new webdriver.Builder()
      .forBrowser('chrome')
      .withCapabilities(chromeCapabilities)
      .build();
      
    driver.get("http://travel.agileway.net")
      driver.getTitle().then(function(the_title){
        assert.equal("Agile Travel", the_title)
      });
    driver.quit
  });
```

I tried running it without mocha but it still didn't work. I don't know what I am doing wrong.